# JavaFX ScrollPane is very slow on Android devices

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am testing JavaFX on Android with the help of jfxmobile-plugin. I am facing performance problems when trying to run it on my android devices. I've seen similar questions and it looks still unresolved in 2018. Someone posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111061/javafx-scrollpane-on-android-too-slow) and it looks still unresolved 3 years latter.

That is what I am using to build my project:

- jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.13 (also tried with jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.28)
- dalvik-sdk (tried version 8.60.7, 8.60.8 and 8.60.9. Version 8.60.10 and 8.60.11 makes the app crash at startup.)

**GluonApplication.Java**

```
package com.gluonapplication;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GluonApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Dashboard.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Rectangle2D r = javafx.stage.Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        Scene s = new Scene(root,r.getWidth(),r.getHeight());
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Dashboard.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="866.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gluonapplication.DashboardController">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <TitledPane text="Alocação">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <PieChart fx:id="c_alocacao" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                              <Label layoutX="431.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Total de Ativos:">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <TableView fx:id="t_ativos" layoutX="447.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="319.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="415.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
                                <columns>
                                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                                </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane text="Movimentação">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <ScrollPane fx:id="sp_aportes" layoutX="10.399999618530273" layoutY="10.399999618530273" prefHeight="320" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                 <content>
                                    <BarChart fx:id="c_aportes" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="862.0">
                                      <xAxis>
                                        <CategoryAxis minHeight="0.0" side="BOTTOM" />
                                      </xAxis>
                                      <yAxis>
                                        <NumberAxis minHeight="0.0" side="LEFT" />
                                      </yAxis>
                                    </BarChart>
                                 </content>
                              </ScrollPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <StackPane>
                     <children>
                      <TitledPane text="Proventos">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane>
                                 <children>
                                    <ScrollPane fx:id="sp_proventos" layoutX="10.399999618530273" layoutY="10.399999618530273" prefHeight="320" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                       <content>
                                          <BarChart fx:id="c_proventos" prefHeight="300">
                                            <xAxis>
                                              <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                                            </xAxis>
                                            <yAxis>
                                              <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                                            </yAxis>
                                          </BarChart>
                                       </content>
                                    </ScrollPane>
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                          </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="p_proventos" progress="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
                  <StackPane>
                     <children>                  
                        <TitledPane text="Fatos Relevantes">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane>
                                 <children>
                                    <TableView fx:id="t_fatos" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="861.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />                              
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                          </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="p_fatos" progress="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.13'
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.29'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

jfxmobile.android.androidSdk = '/home/helder/Android/Sdk'

dependencies {
    //compileNoRetro 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

When I touch the screen I see a lot of text coming to the logcat and I think that it could slow the app even more. So I tried to remove debug calls using proguard (proguardFile on build.gradle) but I was unsuccessful on this task, it made no change to the final apk.

I tried to run the application on Android 4.4 and also on Android 6 and Android 8. All of them were very slow when scrolling. Someone has an idea to improve this and make JavaFX usable on Android devices in 2018?

Comment: There are a few performance hints in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819513/poor-listview-performance-on-gluon). I'd suggest you check if any of those apply to your case. There are quite performant JavaFX apps on Android and iOS, like the Devoxx app ([repo](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devoxx)). And based on your FXML, switching Views is better than having a big scene with everything loaded.

Comment: I've just tested this example: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin-ensemble/src/default/ and the scroll is correctly smooth. Maybe because Ensemble project doesn't use FXML? I cannot imagine why a much more complex Scene runs smoother!

Comment: As mentioned in the question I linked, there are other factors like effects that really make an impact on performance. In general, if the whole area becomes dirty and needs redrawing many times, it is a costly operation. Animated TiledPanes could be a problem. I'd look for different solutions. You can try getting rid of a few things here and there and see if you find what has more impact.

Comment: José, I want to thank you for the insights! I started to test every element of my fxml on a big VBox wrapped in a ScrollPane to see what was really slowing the things down. The Charts and TitledPane was the most slow components. So I enabled caching on these elements by using setCache(true) and setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED). After that, the scroll was smooth almost as an native app. Im at work right now, but tonight I will test these changes on my real app and if works I will mark this question as solved for future reference. Thank you again!

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried the cache trick on my charts and titled panes when I was at home. It performed much better, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569282/5104484) ScrollPaneSkin performed even better, but I still cant compile the patch as is, I had to comment one line due to unresolved references. Any chance that this will be fixed officially? The question is still not solved, because when I scroll by using the scroll bar, it is much faster than by scrolling the center of screen. I'm gonna record a video soon. Also, the ScrollPane became much faster than the scroll of a TableView.

Comment: I also think that JavaFX is very capable of rendering complex Scenes on mobile after enabling cache on the nodes, but the default event handler looks buggy.